# class type required but T found in Encoders

Tags: scala, apache-spark, generics, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to create a generic code to read using spark sql from a view. Where **T** can be any object passed at runtime, I should be able to get DataSet of T.

Method

```
def queryStream[T](sparkSession: SparkSession, query: String, filterParams: Array[String])(implicit tag: ClassTag[T]): Dataset[T] = sparkSession.sql(query)
            .as(Encoders.bean[KafkaMessage](classOf[KafkaMessage]))
            .map(f => {
              init()
              getObjectMapper.readValue(f.message, classTag[T].runtimeClass).asInstanceOf[T]
            })(Encoders.bean[T](classOf[T]))
```

Invocation :

```
queryStream[Student](sparkSession,"select cast(value as string) as message,"
    + "cast(key as string) as messageKey, " +
      "cast(partition as int) partition, " +
      "cast(offset as long) offset from events",null)
```

KafkaMessage:

```
class KafkaMessage {

  @BeanProperty
  var messageKey: String = _

  @BeanProperty
  var message: String = _

  @BeanProperty
  var partition: Int = _

  @BeanProperty
  var offset: Long = _

  override def toString(): String = s"Message Key: $messageKey, Message: $message, Partition:$partition, Offset:$offset"
}
```